# OR operation between columns in SELECT query in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I wonder if it is possible to use OR operation between columns in a SELECT query?

```
select 
  first_name, 
  last_name 
from 
  employee 
where 
  (first_name OR last_name)='&enter_search_string';
```

Comment: Just seperate it into two ideas.   `where first_name='&enter_search_string' OR last_name='&enter_search_string';`

Comment: I dont want to pass the same value twice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just my preference:

```
SELECT first_name,  last_name 
FROM employee 
WHERE '&enter_search_string' IN (first_name, last_name)
```

Answer (score 2):

You neeed to use it like this:

```
select 
  first_name, 
  last_name 
from 
  employee 
where first_name='first_name' OR last_name='last_name';
```